# About definition of "extended absolute value" (in $\overline{\Bbb{R}}=\Bbb{R}\cup\{+\infty,-\infty\}$)

Tags: definition, real-numbers

Is correct following definition?

- ***Def.***: Let be $a \in \overline{\Bbb{R}}=\Bbb{R}\cup\{+\infty,-\infty\}$, $$|a|=\begin{cases}
   |a|& \text{ if } a\in \Bbb{R} \\ 
   +\infty & \text{ if } a \in \{+\infty,-\infty\}
  \end{cases}$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, that would be correct. As would be $$\lvert a\rvert = \begin{cases} -a &, a < 0\\ a &, a \geqslant 0.\end{cases}$$

Comment: @DanielFischer, thanks soo much! ;) :)

Comment: The notation $\overline{\Bbb{R}}^{\{+\infty,-\infty\}}$ is a mystery. One usually writes $\overline{\Bbb{R}}$ for $\Bbb{R}\cup\{+\infty,-\infty\}$.

Comment: ok.. I edit my post! ;)